# How to have an ipywidgets.ToggleButtons with multiple buttons using the same label

Tags: python, ipywidgets

By default, all the `options` for the buttons must be unique.

```
options=["label1","label2",...]
```

You can however provide a list of tuples like this

```
options=[("label1",value1), ("label2",value2),]
```

And that is accepted.

However, if you provide this

```
options=[("label1",value1), ("label2",value2),("label1",value3)]
```

It displays well, behind the scenes provides the good `.value` and `.index`, but visually it selects the first "label1" when you click the second "label1".

[image]

How can I work around that limitation?

Code:

```
import ipywidgets as widgets

realoptions="One word in different location is possibly a different word".split()
options=realoptions

t=widgets.ToggleButtons(
    options=options, 
    description='Choose:',
    disabled=False,
    button_style='', # 'success', 'info', 'warning', 'danger' or ''
    #tooltips=['Description of b1', 'Description of b2', ... ],
  # icons=['check'] * 3
)
t
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple.

Make the labels artificially unique by adding trailing spaces.

```
space=" "
options=[ (x+space*i,x) for i,x in enumerate(realoptions)]
```

Visually it will look the same (to some degree) and since you are using tuples to provide the 'real' value, then all is fine.

[image]

[image]